# Hibernate One To Many

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I am doing  for one to many mapping with no success. My schema is as follows

Event (one) ----> Message (many)

The Get/Set message function in Event File:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event", schema = "public")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Event implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    ....    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "event")
    public Set<Message> getMessages() {
    return this.messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(Set<Message> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
    }
}
```

The Get/Set message function in Message File:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message", schema = "public")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Message implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    ....
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
    public Event getEvent() {
            return this.event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
            this.event = event;
    }
}
```

And Hibernate Configuration File:

```
...
<mapping class="org.itri.ccma.paas.hibernate.Event" />
<mapping class="org.itri.ccma.paas.hibernate.Message" />
```

After Executing following BoEvent.java

```
...
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Event event = new Event();
            session.save(event);

            Set<Message> Messagess = new HashSet<Message>();

            Message testMessage = new Message();
            testMessage.setEvent(event);

            event.getMessages().add(testMessage);
            session.save(event);
            tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();


        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
```

There is no record in my Message table but event table is OK.
I think I am missing something in my code

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your class annotated as `@Entity`? And did you annotate your class as  `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`?

Comment: I think i annotated my class as @Entity already.

Comment: But where should I put @access , event or message or both ?

Comment: btw you save your `event` twice but you never save your `message`

Comment: You are right! After I correct this. I success! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added another way. Instead of saving it explicitly you may want it as cascade. I added a snipped to my answer. How you can do it. Cascade means when you add an event everything thats linked to the event will saved as well (Cascade.All).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add it to every Entity that uses Property-Access means `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` on top of a method-signature like you did. And do add the serial number.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'message')
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Message extends BusinessEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = 'event')
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Event extends BusinessEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

You can have `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` or `@Access(AccessType.Field)` the difference is, where you annotate the `@ManyToOne`(@OneToMany, @OneToOne). Property-access means you set those annotations on top of the method signature. Field-access means you set in on top of the field it self.

like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'event')
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Event extends BusinessEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Message message;

@ManyToOne
public Message getMessage(){ return message;}
//setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = 'event')
@Access(AccessType.Field)
public class Event extends BusinessEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
private Message message;

public Message getMessage(){ return message;}
//setter
}
```

The imports:

```
 import javax.persistence.Access;
 import javax.persistence.AccessType;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Table;
```

As someone mentioned you may get a NPE:

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Event event = new Event();
        session.save(event);

        Message testMessage = new Message();
        testMessage.setEvent(event);
        event.setMessages(new HashSet<Message>());  //the list was not initialized.
        event.getMessages().add(testMessage);
        session.save(event);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();


    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

If you want it saved cascading:

```
  @ManyToOne
  @Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL } )
  public Message getMessage(){ return message;}
```

Comment: After modified the code I have compile error : AccessType cannot be resolved to a variable. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I've added my imports.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added it to my code. But message table still  empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Seems like you are getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Event event = new Event();
        session.save(event);

        Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>();

        Message testMessage = new Message();
        testMessage.setEvent(event);

        messages.add(testMessage); // This
        event.setMessages(messages); // This
        session.save(event);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();


    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for kindly reply. I have modified my code just like this one. But the result is same. I still got nothing in my message table

Answer (score 0):

Based on SWiggels said: 
btw you save your event twice but you never save your message – SWiggels

I modified my code to:

```
...
...
   Message testMessage = new Message();
   testMessage.setEvent(event);
   event.getMessages().add(testMessage);

   session.save(testMessage); // Here I modified
   tx.commit();
```

Finally get the right result. Thanks to SWiggels !

Answer (score 0):

> There is no record in my Message table but event table is OK. I think
>   I am missing something in my code

Because you are not persisting the `testMessage` object.

Why are you persisting the event object twice? Shouldn't you be persisting the `testMessage` object.

```
        Event event = new Event();
        session.save(event);

        Set<Message> Messagess = new HashSet<Message>();

        Message testMessage = new Message();
        testMessage.setEvent(event);

        event.getMessages().add(testMessage);
        session.save(testMessage);  //save testMessage rather than event
        tx.commit();
```